# Wamp-Server 2.5, Localhost not working

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to open localhost like this: `http://localhost/` 
The browsers is telling that it can't connect to `http://localhost/`

I've tried to check port 80 by: `Clicking on wamp icon > Apache > Services > Test port 80` 
I get following result: `Your port 80 is not actually used`

Can someone help me to get localhost working?

Comment: What colour is your wampmanager icon that sits in the system tray?

Comment: green, i reinstalled wamp now it seems to work.

Answer (score 8):

Click on wamp icon > Apache > Services > Install Service.

This solved the problem for me. You can try this.

Comment: Click on wamp icon > Apache > Services > Install Service . After that stop all services in my wampser then restart all services it works

Answer (score 0):

You should also ensure that 
you have the latest versions of the VC11 C++ runtime: [ [www.microsoft.com] ]
Note: If you use a Windows 64-bit version, you must install both 32 and 64 bits versions of the VC11 (2012) runtime.

And to solved port 80 issue try following it work for me: 
Click on wamp icon > Apache > Services > Install Service.

After making changes dont forget to restart all services.
this work for me, save my day thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, Skype was interfering with WAMP, if I closed skype, everything worked fine. (on windows 8.1)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstallation and then re-installing worked for me.

I didn't tried to install Apache service ( as I was not aware of that method at that time). You should try that first.

I have wamp 2.5 on windows 10.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

For me I got the same problem saying that the port 80 is being used by another application. I tried installing the service by clicking on system tray wamp icon > Apache > Services > Install Service.

Then it displayed the message saying port 80 is being used by another application and it also suggested the application (in my case it was skype). I closed the skype runnning in my system tray and tried installing the serviceby clicking on system tray wamp icon > Apache > Services > Install Service.
The it installed successfully and restarted the all the services under  wamp icon > Apache > Services.

And it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the following file from the path:
`c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\httpd.conf`

In the file, search for `Listen 80`.

Change the line `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080` (or another available port number).

Save the file and close it.

After that make sure that your address is http://localhost:8080/ in your browser.

Answer (score -2):

If you are install wamp server, i need install to the icuuc51.dll to windows\system32 and Windows\SysWOW64.

When you init the server his dont show the message to install this dll.

http://pt.dll-files.com/icuuc51.dll.html

Detail. the wamp do not can start by the icon you need run manually the httpd.exe
C:\wamp_2\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe